# Sort ps result but with the first row instantly unchanged

Tags: sort

I want to sort all the processes by Memory

```
me@host:~$ ps au | sort -r -k 5 | head -10 | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
me    2312  0.0  0.1 958148  5568 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
me    2232  0.0  0.2 957248  7912 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
me    2292  0.0  0.3 949556 11924 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:15 nautilus-desktop
me    3308  0.0  0.0 918708  2596 pts/0    Sl   Mar11   0:04 /home/me/.lantern/bin/lantern
me    4728  0.1  0.5 872048 21648 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   1:00 gnome-control-center
me    2223  0.0  0.2 833712  8656 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:04 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-color
me   14638  0.0  0.2  83136 10400 pts/0    S+   13:25   0:00 aria2c https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg
me    1799  1.8  1.2 745516 49592 tty2     Sl+  Mar11  17:36 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
me    3587  0.0  0.4 736908 16952 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:32 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=9889395698754715859,17788752790984658481,131072 --service-pipe-token=121279454012343526 --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=41f7a813-8595-4f48-8ba9-5b4493af761c, --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=121279454012343526 --renderer-client-id=22 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
```

Observe the 5th field, 83136 is judged greater than 745515

I add  '--numeric-sort'

```
me@host:~$ ps au | sort -rn -k 5 | head -10 | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
me    2048  1.3  3.6 3324476 143932 tty2   Sl+  Mar11  12:30 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
me    3323  0.7  5.3 2110972 210872 pts/0  Sl   Mar11   6:54 /home/me/.lantern/bin/lantern
me    3217  0.1  3.1 1834724 124076 tty2   Sl+  Mar11   1:02 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=9889395698754715859,17788752790984658481,131072 --service-pipe-token=14274241015953851945 --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=41f7a813-8595-4f48-8ba9-5b4493af761c, --extension-process --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=14274241015953851945 --renderer-client-id=5 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
me    2932  1.0  4.3 1463616 172764 tty2   SLl+ Mar11   9:54 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
me    2700  0.0  2.3 1263084 93984 tty2    SLl+ Mar11   0:14 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
me    2312  0.0  0.1 958148  5568 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify
me    2232  0.0  0.1 957248  7632 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
me    2292  0.0  0.6 949556 26132 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   0:15 nautilus-desktop
me    3308  0.0  0.0 918708  2584 pts/0    Sl   Mar11   0:04 /home/me/.lantern/bin/lantern
me    4728  0.1  0.5 872048 21588 tty2     Sl+  Mar11   1:00 gnome-control-center
```

but the leading captain description disappears

How could I sort the output but instantly allow the first row take the lead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'ps' command supports sorting natively.  You don't need to resort to piping it to the separate 'sort' command which is removing the header.

To sort on resident memory,

```
ps au --sort -rss | head -10
```

or for virtual memory,

```
ps au --sort -vsz | head -10
```

I believe the second option will match what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

`ps au | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -r --numeric-sort -k 5)| head -10 | sed "s/$USER/me/g`

You can find more answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11856/169181)